# ip address matching with subnetmask in java

Tags: java, ip-address

I have the following scenario: Suppose I receive a packet which has an Ipv4 address. I need to execute certain methods based upon the matching of this IP address with a certain subnetmask. I would like to make an if instruction based on IP and mask.

Example: suppose the condition to pass is that the destination IP address of a packet needs to be `150.0.0.0/8`. If I get a packet with an IP address `150.1.1.1` then the packet is processed, whereas if I get a packet with IP `151.2.2.2` then the packet would simply be ignored.

How do I set such a rule?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public long ipToLong(String ipAddress) {

    long result = 0;

    String[] ipAddressInArray = ipAddress.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {

        long ip = Long.parseLong(ipAddressInArray[3 - i]);

        //left shifting 24,16,8,0 and bitwise OR

        //1. 192 << 24
        //1. 168 << 16
        //1. 1   << 8
        //1. 2   << 0
        result |= ip << (i * 8);

    }

    return result;
  }
long gw = ipToLong("150.0.0.0") // i assume you converted the ip to a 32bit unsigned int
int netmaskBits = 8; // in your example you had: /8, so this is 8

// clear the right-most bits, leave only the leftmost 8 bits
long netmask = (gw>>(32-netmaskBits))<<(32-netmaskBits); 

long ip = ipToLong("150.1.1.1");
long maskedIp = (ip>>(32-netmaskBits))<<(32-netmaskBits); 
if (maskedIp == netmask) {System.out.println("allowed")}
```

Comment: Great answer, I like how you gave the answer. I gave him a simple explanation and left him calculate, but you gave the solution. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it like this:

```
151.1.1.1 &
255.0.0.0
```

This gives you the network address. ANd if the address matches `150.0.0.0`, then you accept the package. It's a simple logic `and`.

Comment: i know the correspendences of /8 is 255.0.0.0 or /24 is 255.255.255.0 but i need the version in java code

Comment: You need to convert the decimal number into binary. I am sure that is not a problem for you :).... For example, 255 -> 11111111. You just take each part of the ip (150, 0, 0 and 0) and do a logical `and` with each value from your netmask.